# How to create animation in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Recently, i have been writing a single page app using backbone. When i try to create a animation like throwing a card but i can't use jquery to do this. I found that after backbone view call this render(). I try to select DOM element by jquery and modify it. It didn't change anything? Does anybody know this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#logo { 
position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    <image id="card" src='10.png'/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="di chuyển"/>
</script>
<script src="move.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

(function($){
    var aniView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#template').html()),

        events:{
            "mouseover input[type=button]":"moveCard"
        },

        moveCard:function () {
            alert('di chuyển');
            move('#card')
                .add('margin-left', 100)
                .end();
        },

        render:function () {
            $('#container').html(this.template());
        }

    }); 

    var a = new aniView();
    a.render();
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you share the relevant code pieces with us? It's easy to do animations with jquery-ui for example.

Comment: It may be worth noting that when inside a `Backbone.View` it's not necessary to select the View's element manually with jQuery, instead you can use [this.$el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el)

Comment: i insert my code in my question. Something goes wrong in my code. :(

Comment: where this `move` method came from?

Comment: move method from move.js. http://visionmedia.github.com/move.js/